# Flutter: TextFormField's enter button to execute GestureDetector Function

Tags: flutter

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.email_outlined,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      labelText: 'email',),
  onChanged: (v) {
    _emailV = v;
  },
);

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
      child: Text(
    'emaaail',
  )),
);
```

I have these two widgets inside the `Column()`. When a user finishes typing an email address and press `done`, I want the app to execute `GestureDetector - onTap()` function.

I'd tried with the context and stuff but did not work as expected. So, I wonder if there is any thing that I can make this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function

```
// depending on your needs
void onTapFunction(){
   ...
}
```

add the function to the onTap in the gesture part

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: onTapFunction,
  child: Container(
      child: Text(
    'emaaail',
  )),
);
```

add the function to the onEditingComplete in the TextFormField part

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.email_outlined,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      labelText: 'email',),
  onChanged: (v) {
    _emailV = v;
  },
   onEditingComplete: onTapFunction,
          
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try Inkwell() instead of GestureDetector() if you only want the ontap function to be executed;

```
Inkwell(
     onTap: () {
          //write your function
          },
      child: Container(
              child: Text(
                     'emaaail',
                     )),
              );
     )
```